# ruby google_drive gem how to access google drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now with the deprecated google-login feature with google_drive gem, I'm wondering how I can access a spreadsheet?

I've tried to follow guidelines below, but the link to getting a client_secret is broken. I went to google developers and gotten myself a json file that includes client_ID, but right now my simple code outputs a link to getting authorization code but I'm not sure how to use that authorization code.

```
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/1.0.5
```

Can someone help me use this gem to access my spreadsheet?

I'm basically trying to follow the example from the documentation.

```
require "google/api_client"
require "google_drive"

# Creates a session. This will prompt the credential via command line for the
# first time and save it to config.json file for later usages.
session = GoogleDrive.saved_session("config.json")

# First worksheet of
# https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=pz7XtlQC-PYx-jrVMJErTcg
# Or https://docs.google.com/a/someone.com/spreadsheets/d/pz7XtlQC-PYx-jrVMJErTcg/edit?usp=drive_web
ws = session.spreadsheet_by_key("pz7XtlQC-PYx-jrVMJErTcg").worksheets[0]

# Gets content of A2 cell.
p ws[2, 1]  #==> "hoge"

# Changes content of cells.
# Changes are not sent to the server until you call ws.save().
ws[2, 1] = "foo"
ws[2, 2] = "bar"
ws.save
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The authorization code thing will only come up once ( the first time you try to access the doc )

When I tried this, I tried it through the console, and I had a response as follow:

Google::APIClient - Initializing client with options {:application_name=>"google_drive Ruby library", :application_version=>"0.4.0"}

```
1. Open this page:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=***************************&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%20https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/

2. Enter the authorization code shown in the page:
```

On going to the given URL, I got the authorization code like you mentioned. So, what I did was to copy the code and paste it as directed above ( `2. Enter the authorization code shown in the page:` )

And that was it.

A new file was created in my application directory with the credentials as well as the refresh token and everything.